# how to resolve an issue showing multiple slider at once using owl-carousel

Tags: jquery, slider, owl-carousel

I was trying to use owl carousel for multiple slides working in each tab menu with by clicking li in ul.

here is my HTML

```
<ul class="artwork">
        <li class="on">Pattern</li>
        <li>Colours</li>
        <li>Characters</li>
        <li>Photography</li>
        <li>Drwaings</li>
        <li>Illustrations</li>
        <li>Nature</li>
    </ul>


    <div class="tab_cont">
        <div class="my-1">
            <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
                <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
                <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
                <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
                <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
                <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="my-2">
            <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
                <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
                <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
                <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
                <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
                <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="my-3">
            <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
                <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
                <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
                <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
                <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
                <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and css here

```
.artwork {
        border: 1px solid red;
        padding-bottom: 100px;
    }
    .artwork li {
        font-family: 'Montserrat-Semibold';
        list-style: none;
        float: left;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: .8rem;
    }
    .artwork li:nth-child(n+2) {
        margin-left: 40px;
    }

    .artwork li.on {
        color: #AE1824;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .tab_cont {
        clear: both;
        border: 1px solid #dedede;
        height: auto;
        background-color: #cecece;
    }




    .my-1 {
    max-width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
    .my-2 {
        max-width:1000px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }

    .my-3 {
        max-width:1000px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }

.my-1 > .owl-carousel > .owl-stage-outer > .owl-stage > .owl-item > .item {
    background-color:red;
    margin:0 auto;
    height: 320px;
}
.my-2 > .owl-carousel > .owl-stage-outer > .owl-stage > .owl-item > .item {
    background-color:blue;
    margin:0 auto;
    height: 320px;
}
.my-3 > .owl-carousel > .owl-stage-outer > .owl-stage > .owl-item > .item {
    background-color:black;
    margin:0 auto;
    height: 320px;
}
```

and here is jquery for switching tab menu and running owl carousel

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(".artwork li").click(function() {
                var idx = $(this).index();
                $(".artwork li").removeClass("on");
                $(".artwork li").eq(idx).addClass("on");
                $(".tab_cont > div").hide();
                $(".tab_cont > div").eq(idx).show();
            })
        });
    $('.my-1 > .owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:3000,
    autoplayHoverPause:true,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
});
$('.my-2 > .owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:3000,
    autoplayHoverPause:true,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
});
$('.my-3 > .owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:3000,
    autoplayHoverPause:true,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
});
```

the problem is...
Those 3 tab menu are appearing at once when i open the page at first even though i hided in jQuery

but it disappears when i click one of li to switch the slides.
I want to see only one slide at first.

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide them after you call $(...).owlCarousel({})

Comment: i tried to make a function to hide them, but it does not work... they are shown at the very first when i open the page